# Estimates of the Quantile Regression

Tags: regression, least-squares, quantiles, quantile-regression

In the Quantile regresion model we assume that$$y_i=x_i^T\beta +\epsilon_i,\ i=1, 2, 3, ....,n$$ such that the conditional quantiles of the error terms are zero and for the OLS model we assume that the means of the error terms are zero. I have some problems regarding this:
$$$$1. While doing simulations we generate data with the error terms having distributions $N(0, 1),  
\ \chi^2_5, \ \text{Student's}-t$. But in these distributions not all the quantiles are zero and for the $\chi^2_5$ distribution even the mean is not zero. Also if $\epsilon_{i_s}$ follow any distribution then they cannot have all their quantiles zero. So this violates the assumptions of the QR model.
$$$$2. Is it necessary that when the conditional distributions of the dependent variables are independent and identical then the QR estimates and the OLS estimates for the slope parameter are expected to be almost same (if yes why)? Also is it only true when there is some linear relation between the variables because when I generated ten thousand $x_{i_s}$ from $N(10, 1)$ and $y_i=e^{x_i}+\epsilon_i, \ \epsilon_i \sim N(0, 1)$ then the QR estimates and the OLS estimates for the slope parameter were different by a significant margin?

Comment: It sounds like there are some fundamental issues with your understanding of quantile regression (QR). We don't fit the model "such that the conditional quantiles of the error terms are zero". Rather, we optimize the parameters for a very particular loss function (the pinball loss), which has the key property that predictions will be conditional quantiles of the outcome. Roger Koenker popularized the concept, and [there is a lot of material out there](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=koenker+quantile+regression). I think understanding that would help you a lot.

Comment: We fit the model $$y_i=x^T_i\beta+\epsilon_i$$ and then assume that the conditional quantile of $y_i$ is $x_i^T\beta$ then this implies that the quantile of the error term is zero.

Comment: One question: what would the distributions of the $\varepsilon_i$ be conditional on?  Usually error terms are assumed independent of each other and everything else.  When the assumption applies to the conditional quantiles of the $y_i,$ as in your comment, that does not imply the differences $y_i-x_i^\prime\beta$ must be identically distributed (or even terribly meaningful), which makes for an unnecessarily difficult model formulation -- and that's not what is usually meant by quantile regression.